# No puedo seleccionar registros de una tabla

Tags: python, sqlite3

estoy haciendo un programa que me haga menús. Para ello estoy utilizan un entorno virtual de python 3.9 con virtualenv y sqlite3. El código es el siguiente:

```
import sqlite3

from sqlite3 import Error

def sql_connection():

    try:

        con = sqlite3.connect('myDatabase.db')

        print('conectado')

        return con

    except Error:

        print('Error')

def buscar_platos(con):

    cursor_obj = con.cursor()

    cursor_obj.execute('SELECT * FROM platos')

    rows = cursor_obj.fetchall()

    for row in rows:

        print(row)

con = sql_connection()

buscar_platos(con)
```

Al ejecutar el código me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/miguelflorez/Developer/myProjects/python/menu_maker/main.py", line 33, in <module>
    buscar_platos(con)
  File "/Users/miguelflorez/Developer/myProjects/python/menu_maker/main.py", line 23, in buscar_platos
    cursor_obj.execute('SELECT * FROM platos')
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: platos
```

Lo he comprobado y el nombre de la tabla es platos. ¿Por qué me sale el error?

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes poner  la parte del código donde creas/abres la base de datos porfavor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si en verdad existe tu tabla "platos" en la base de datos `myDatabase.db`, el problema que indica:

> sqlite3.OperationalError: no such table: xxxxxx

tal vez sea la ruta donde trata de abrir la base de datos que serìa en el directorio de trabajo y en realidad no existe ahì:

```
 con = sqlite3.connect('myDatabase.db')
```

te sugiero crear la conexiòn de esta forma:

```
import os.path

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
dbPath = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "myDatabase.db")

con = sqlite3.connect(dbPath)
```

Comment: Ya me funciona, muchas gracias.